# windows audio running but no notification bar icon

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, icons, services

Windows 7 64bit, VIA audio chipset

I just updated some of my drivers using IObit Driver Booster (which is a recognized software developer group), but since the update, I noticed no audio icon on my notification bar

I check the windows audio services and all are enabled and running, but the notification bar icon says the service is not running...

any thoughts or suggestions, yes I can revert to previous drivers but that is a last resort

Comment: What have you tried already to rectify the problem? What were the results?  Really though - go get the actual driver set from the device's manufacturer and install it that way.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I assume you are the one too downvote my post/question... I thank you for that, your downvote is appreciated, and secondly, I havent tried anything since there is nothing to try except rolling back to the previous driver, but that isnt the problem, the software looks for the same driver, but just a later release and then updates the existing driver, and would you also be so kind as to find the VIA VT1802 chipset software on VIA's website, I would give you a medal if you are ABLE to find it, and I mean the latest version, not just the 1 release of it...

Comment: http://download.viatech.com/en/support/driversSelect.jsp -> "This driver supports and has WHQL for the following HD audio chips ONLY: VT1705, VT1802P, VT1819S, VT1708S and **VT2021**.These are general sound effects drivers with common functions. System manufacturers and motherboard vendors customize audio hardware and software, so to ensure optimal sound quality and compatibility, **we strongly recommend you obtain the system-validated and certified audio drivers directly from your system manufacturer or motherboard manufacturer, not from VIA."**

Comment: What's the [hardware ID](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-Hardware-ID) of the sound card?

Answer (score 0):

Start / Control Panel / Notification Area Icons:

Select "Turn system items on of off"

[image]

Make sure "Volume" is set to "On"

[image]

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, but next to the volume text, it says in small italics writing, "Windows audio service is not running", but in services.msc it is...